# How to show the hidden child form again

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I need to show the hidden form again. But when I tried form.show() or form.visible = true I'm getting this error.

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll
>
> Additional information: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

This is my code for showing the hidden form:

```
foreach (Form f in this.MdiChildren)
{
    if (f.Visible == false)
    {
        f.Activate();
        f.Visible = true;
        f.TopMost = true;
     }
}
```

Code for hiding form

```
private void HideAll() 
{ 
    foreach (Form child in this.MdiChildren) 
    { 
        child.Hide(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you'd better use the `Show` and `Hide` methods.

Comment: hi dcg ! see my description above. I have tried that too. Getting the same error. Please tell me why am i getting those errors. @dcg

Comment: Nobody can tell you from the code you've shown, it's not enough to give an answer. The error doesn't even seem related to showing/hiding a form.

Comment: private void HideAll()
        {
            foreach (Form child in this.MdiChildren)
            {
                               child.Hide();
                                      
          }} .This is the code for hiding form.  And i want to show the hidden form again. @Equalsk

Comment: I think you need to call form.BringToFront(); because the form is already opened and kept hidden in background not closed.

Comment: Try swapping the order `f.Activate();` with `f.Visible = true;`. When MDI hides a child it destroys the form and recreates it when visible is true. I think the error is caused when you try to activate a destroyed child.

Comment: guys i have tried all ways. Still same error message occurs. Very sad. @Equalsk

Comment: @TaW Any solution?? I have tried many ways.

Comment: Your code works just fine. The exception is caused by some other part of your program. Did you look into the  error/call stack ???

Comment: _When MDI hides a child it destroys the form and recreates it when visible is true._ This is nonsense; the invisible Forms are all intact and keep all their data and state values, of course..!

Comment: This code is fine.  The error must be somewhere else.  Did one of the forms do something on visible changing to false to break the ability to show it again?

Comment: I have still not solved this issue. And Yes you are correct .Problem is not with code.All other forms are working fine with hide and show. But in this form, iam using ocx function in this form to populate a tree view. After hiding the form when i try to visible. The form is opening, but when it tries to show the tree view, iam getting this error. "An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll

Additional information: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt." @TaW

Comment: @David see the above comments and advise me if any solutions available

Comment: Well, as you found the issue is not with the code you posted. I think the best course of action is to delete the question altogether and post a new one with the code that creates/uses that ocx function! Or you could update it..